# How to perform data factory transformations on large datasets in Azure data warehouse

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, azure-data-factory

We have Data warehouse tables that we perform transformations using ADF.

If I have a group of ADW tables, and I need to perform transformations on them to land them back onto ADW, should I save the transformations into Azure Blob Storage? or go direct into the target table.

The ADW tables are in excess of 100Mil records.

Is it an acceptable practice to use Blob Storage as the middle piece.

Comment: How do you want  perform transformations on them? Create new tables to receive the data or rollback to table itself?

Comment: upsert to a new table.  Thanks

Comment: Can you please confirm if you are using the product Azure Synapse Analytics formerly known as Azure SQL Data Warehouse?   That will help set the context as it's not tagged.  Can you also explain a bit more about the **type** of transformations you want to do?  Maybe with some examples.  I'm not sure I understand the reasons for wanting to do them outside of SQL DW.  Or to put it another way, why not do them inside SQL DW?

Comment: yes.  Synapse Analytics  we have usually standard stuff. Lookups, Joins, Calculated Fields, normal stuff.  In standard etl, ie. using Talend, we would utilize Blob Storage as a launching point for the target table since bulk exec inserts are much faster for this kind of thing.  Ididn't know if ADF solves that issue, or should I continue using blob storage.

Comment: Lookups, joins, calculated fields are all database operations, so why not do it in the database?  You'll be paying a lot of money for Synapse, why not use it?  Use joins on hash distributed tables and CTAS. 
 Consider scaling up temporarily to do the processing and scale down when you are finished.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two ways to do this (they do not require moving the data into blob storage),

- Do the transformation within SQL DW using stored procedure and use ADF to orchestrate the stored procedure call
- Use ADF's data flow to apply the transformation to read from SQL DW and write back to SQL DW

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'd better using the use Blob Storage as the middle piece.

You can not copy the tables from SQL DW(Source) to the same SQL DW(Sink) directly! If you have tried this， you will have the problems:

1. Copy data: has the error in data mapping, copy data to the same table, not create new tales.
2. Copy Active: Table is required for Copy activity.

If you want to copy the data from SQL DW tables to  new tables with Data Factor, you need at least two steps:

1. copy the data from the SQL DW tables to Blob storage(create the csv
   files).
2. Load these csv files to SQL DW and create new tables.

Reference tutorials:

- [Copy and transform data in Azure Synapse Analytics (formerly Azure
  SQL Data Warehouse) by using Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-sql-data-warehouse)
- [Copy and transform data in Azure Blob storage by using Azure Data
  Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage)

Data Factory is good at transfer big data. Reference [Copy performance of Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-performance#copy-performance-and-scalability-achievable-using-adf). I think it may faster than [SELECT - INTO Clause (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-into-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @Leon....I meant I was deriving Table B from TableA using lookups oand joins via TableD